# WD Caviar SATA extra power cord or not

Tags: hard-drive

I have a WD Caviar Green. If I connect this to my motherboard then will I need another cable for power or do I just plug and play?

I am running Windows 7 64 bit and have a Gigabyte 78lmt-USB3.

Comment: what are you talking about? are you saying that will you need the data cable AND a power cable for the hard drive? yes. Unless you're using eSATA and it has enough power for the HDD built in

Comment: Yes;  You need both cables require for SATA devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OS has nothing to do with how you connect it. You just need two cables to connect a regular [SATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA) drive like this Caviar. One cable for data, an other cable for power.

```
The data cable:             The power cable:
```

[image]

<sup>Images copied from Wikipedia</sup>

After connecting both cables and booting you may need to partition the drive. **May** because the manufacturer may already have put data on the disk. If not you will need to add a partition table (GPT), add partitions, format those and mount the volumes.

Comment: Nitpick detail: You could connect a SATA drive to a single [SAS](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NaBjv.png) connector. Almost certainly not what the OP is looking for though.

Answer (score 0):

All internal hard drives require two cables that attach to them. Older drives require an `IDE` ribbon cable and a 4 pin `molex` power cable. Sata on the other hand require a `sata data` cable and a `sata power` cable. If you do not have any more `sata power` cables coming out of your power supply, you can get an adapter for pretty cheap.

Note: I do not know the actual names for the cables. Please let me know in a comment if you happen to know them.